# If symmetric matrices $A$ and $B$ are similar, are they necessarily orthogonally similar

Tags: matrices, orthogonal-matrices, similar-matrices

An affirmative answer is claimed on page 3 [here](http://www.law05.si/law17/presentations/Pkokol.pdf) (unless I misunderstand),

> Lemma:
> If two symmetric matrices $A$ and $B$ are similar, then they are orthogonally similar.

but I was unable to find a proof or citation.

To understand this claim I considered the simple case of

$$
A = \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & i \\
 1 & i & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right), \qquad
B = \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 i \sqrt{2} & 1 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 & -i \sqrt{2} \\
\end{array}
\right),
$$
which (by virtue of their Jordan normal form) are both similar to the matrix
$$
J = 
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right).
$$
The aforementioned Lemma then claims that $A$ and $B$ are related by a similarity transformation $A = P B P^{-1}$, such that $P$ is equal to its inverse transpose: $P = P^{-T}$. Following pointers from @chhro I see that
$$
P = \frac{1}{4}\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 -i & -3 \sqrt{2} & i \\
 -3 & i \sqrt{2} & 3 \\
 -2 \sqrt{2} & 0 & -2 \sqrt{2} \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
is a solution. However I would be grateful for reference for the general claim.

Comment: For a pair of similar matrices, a matrix of similarity is non-unique. Even though you have that $P$ above, it doesn't mean it's the one referred to by the Lemma.

Comment: Does this follow from the fact that real symmetric matrices are diagonalisable by an orthogonal change of basis?

Comment: @preferred_anon not all symmetric matrices are diagonalisable (see e.g. $A$ and $B$ above)

Comment: @chhro, good point. Nonetheless the question stands.

Comment: @Ruy, it is true that if two complex symmetric matrices are similar, they are complex orthogonally similar. Could be Horn et al who proved it, I forget.

Comment: @Ruy the example $A$ above is from the source. I am confident the source is not restricted to either real or hermitian matrices.

Comment: @Ruy please see https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.01837 and references therein.

Comment: I have deleted all of my previous comments, since they only expressed my surprise, and probably also my ignorance, at the appearence of symmetric complex matrices.  I'll try to get myself better informed about this issue.

Comment: @chhro Thank you. If you can post a citation I will accept the answer.

Comment: @ComptonScattering, it's Theorem 20 in this paper (take S=I). https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379593000566

Comment: Wonderful, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@chhro](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/255099/chhro) mentions the answer to the question is yes, and the proof follows from Theorem 20 of [Horn and Merino](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379593000566). However, a more direct proof is also provided in the later work of [Bukovšek and Omladic](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0024379517303300?via%3Dihub):

We assume $A = A^T$, $B = B^T$, $A = P B P^{-1}$ and wish to construct complex orthogonal matrix $O$ ($OO^T = I$) such that $A = O B O^T$.

From the premise we have $A P = P B$, by transposition we have $P^T A = B P^T$, and multiplication by $P$ we have $P P^T A = P B P^T = A P P^T$ hence $A$ and $PP^T$ commute.

Let $R$ be the square root of the complex symmetric invertible matrix $PP^T$: $R^2  = PP^T$, [$R$ is symmetric](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/376970/why-does-an-invertible-complex-symmetric-matrix-always-have-a-complex-symmetric), invertible, and commutes with $A$.

Let $O = R^{-1}P$. $O$ is complex orthogonal $OO^T = R^{-1}P P^T R^{-1} = R^{-1}R^2 R^{-1} = I$. Moreover, $O$ relates $A$ and $B$ in the manner desired: $A O = A R^{-1} P = R^{-1} A P = R^{-1} P B = O B$.